# Delegate objects produce duplicate code: (inheritance vs delegates)

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, delegates

I have ran into a situation within the OOP Java world that has stumped me while figuring out the ideal way to structure my code for "test-ability". The research that I have done has mostly pointed to delegates, which is a cool, straightforward [pattern](https://programmingideaswithjake.wordpress.com/2015/05/09/replacing-inheritance-with-composition/), however, I believe it results in a ton of duplicate code.

In summary, I have a class with some lengthy methods. I have a second class that 'extends' the aforementioned, lengthy class and overrides a few of said methods. The second class calls the super method while overriding the original (thus the first class is completely necessary to reducing code).

Example:
The stripped down parent:

```
public class ParentClass {

  public void methodX(final int source, final int target) {
   ++++
   ++++
   ++++
  }
}
```

The stripped down child:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

  @Override
  public void methodX(final int source, final int target) {
    super.methodX(source, target)
    ****
    ****
    **** // extra logic
  }
}
```

My thoughts and issues:

Writing a test class for the ChildClass (class that is extending and overriding its parents methods) is incredibly difficult because we call a super method! The super method is heavily critical in avoiding duplicate test code i.e. the code to test ParentClass will have to be used in ChildClass. I can mock a lot of these internal methods manually with Mockito, but it definitely seems like terrible practice.

My questions:

Is this a fair way to use a super method or extend a class like this at all (child classes should be avoided -- composition > inheritance)?
Is it necessary to test the ParentClass whenever we test the child classes?
What design patterns would be used to refactor the code appropriately to avoid this situation?

Comment: Even though composition is much preferred over inheritance, the boilerplate code to set up delegating to the composed is, unfortunately, necessary in Java - which is too bad.  There are languages that do this delegation for you automatically - for example, there is the JVM language Kotlin, and I beleive golang does the same thing.  Project Lombok, which focusses on cutting down on the Java boilerplate code, has an 'experimental' delegation feature you might want to take a look at: https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are various "smells" in your input:

- You start with violating java coding conventions. Class names start UpperCase; but that is just a side note.
- The first real issue I see: having multiple implementations of `methodX()`; and making that call to the *super* implementation an **essential** part within your subclass override. That introduces very tight coupling between your classes.

I would start with that point - and look into getting rid of it; but in case you can't or do not want to; then it is absolutely essential that you do not "mock" away that super call. You want to make sure that your tests for your sub classes do run that code they depend on.

To the contrary: if you find that you can't reasonably test your child classes without that mocking tricks; then that is *another* indication that something is amiss within in your code base.

Comment: Forgive the style mistakes (this was done on the fly without an IDE).

Excellent point on the coupling. We assume the super call as a native part of the extended class and therefore just as important to test.

How would you recommend we 'decouple' these classes? I know we can create a helper class. Is there another design change we can make to follow a pattern of some sort?

Comment: I am close to call it a day for today. And I find your example a bit to unspecific for me to come up with great ideas. But if you are willing to add "more code"; and drop me a note, I *might* have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Feel free to add another comment whenever you wish (your reply was sufficient and appreciated).

I am going to add some example code, but the content of said code does not matter given my situation... Realistically, all the code could be print statements and it wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a fair way.

Extending means defining an "is a" relationship.

A Mazda IS A Car.

Therefore, it is fair (and necessary) to test that Mazda can actually do everything a Car does, and it's more than OK that Mazda reuses whatever it can from Car.

To avoid (or minimize) the code duplication between `CarTest` and `MazdaTest`, you can use `CarTestHelper`, and put all test code you want to reuse there, in static helper methods.

Comment: I agree with your points. I think your best addition was the helper class.